# call different controller via RestClient in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

Hi I'm developing apis for my rails app, my rails app will act like a sever for 
those who call these apis.

I have built an api which gives the roles present in database.
When I hit this url on the browser `http://localhost:3000/apis/roles` it is 
working fine but when I'm 
calling it from my controller the code stops execting and the page keeps on 
loading

below is my code

```
 def new
      uri = "http://localhost:3000/apis/roles"  # controller => apis/roles , action => index
      response = RestClient.get uri # code stops here 
      debugger
       render json: {
        message: "hello users"
      }
  end
```

when I press Clt+c to stop the server I'm getting this issue `ThreadError: 
Attempt to unlock a mutex which is locked by another thread`

any Idea why I'm getting this

Comment: Can i ask something? Is it the same server?

Comment: yes this is the same server

Comment: Actually I have made the apis and I'm testing it by calling it from another controller

Comment: I would suggest to use another application or process to test it. Its just a guess but i am thinking RestClient is trying to spawn another thread which it is not allowed to.